# Multi cURL only uploads one image

Tags: php, arrays, image, curl, upload

I have the following code to upload images to a external server. The problem is that it only uploads one image from the array instead of all images in the array, where is the problem :)?

```
  $images = explode(',', $details['images']);
  $mh             = curl_multi_init();
  $sequenceNumber = 1;
  foreach ($images as $i => $url) {
      if (file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/tmp/' . $delad . '_' . $sequenceNumber . '.jpg')) {
          $uploadfile = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/tmp/' . $delad . '_' . $sequenceNumber . '.jpg';
      } else {
          copy($url, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/tmp/' . $delad . '_' . $sequenceNumber . '.jpg');
          $uploadfile = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/tmp/' . $delad . '_' . $sequenceNumber . '.jpg';
      }
      $conn[$i] = curl_init("http://*/image.html");
      curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
          'sequenceNumber' => $sequenceNumber,
          'imageData' => "@" . $uploadfile . ";type=image/png",
          'filename' => $url
      ));
      curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $conn[$i]);
      $sequenceNumber++;
  }

  do { $n=curl_multi_exec($mh,$active); } while ($active);

  foreach ($images as $i => $url) {
       //$res[$i]=curl_multi_getcontent($conn[$i]);
       curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$conn[$i]);
       curl_close($conn[$i]);
}
  curl_multi_close($mh);
```

$details['images'] is just a url list of images seperated by a comma e.g.

```
http://google.com/stackoverflow-logo.png,http://google.com/stackoverflow2.png
```

Comment: I will add this to the post, thanks. Receiving side of the setup i have no control over.

Comment: No control of the receiving side, it's strange because when I do a single curl in a foreach for the image urls the all get uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments on the original question, the original poster states that they do not have control of the receiving end of the setup, but when they do a single curl within a `foreach` loop, the image gets uploaded.

If that is the case, perhaps the receiving side is simply unable to handle too many requests at once. So I would suggest adding a [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) setting in your script to pause between uploads to give the receiving side the chance to catch up.

So at the very bottom of the first `foreach()` loop:

```
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $conn[$i]);
      $sequenceNumber++;
  }
```

Add a `sleep()` command like so:

```
      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $conn[$i]);
      $sequenceNumber++;
      sleep(10);
  }
```

Since `sleep()` uses seconds, I have set it to 10 seconds. Feel free to adjust that based in your script results & app needs.